# InsertRow with NSFetchedResultsControllerdelegate

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3

This should be trivial but I can't get it working.

I want to move a row in a UITableView in a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

I can easily delete rows, but inserting doesn't seem to work (NSInternalInconsistencyException).

I am trying

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destinationindex = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [destinationindex], with: .fade)
}
```

I have also tried

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let delobject = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
    fetchedResultsController?.managedObjectContext.delete(delobject!)
    fetchedResultsController?.managedObjectContext.insert(delobject!)
}
```

Of course a simple delete works; for example swipe to delete:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if (indexPath.row != 0) {
            let delobject = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
            fetchedResultsController?.managedObjectContext.delete(delobject!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model must fit the `tableView` so number of items in data equals number of rows in `tableView`.

A `FetchedResultsController` based `TableView` reflects the results of a CoreData fetch request. Inserting a row in the `UITableView` means inserting a new entry in CoreData.

And that is what you want to do: Create a new entry in Core Data (Like you do already do when deleting a row).

Comment: I did try something like this - if I deleted a row, and immediatly inserted it I would not expect it just to delete. But the following code does just that       let delobject = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
        fetchedResultsController?.managedObjectContext.delete(delobject!)
        fetchedResultsController?.managedObjectContext.insert(delobject!)

Comment: You do not delete `delobject`. For your understanding, create a _new_ object in CoreData in `didSelectRow` first.

Comment: If I delete and insert, all that happens is the row deletes (does not insert)

Comment: You have to handle this in the `FetchedResutlsControllerDelegate` methods. [This tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/implement-the-nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-protocol-with-swift-3/) might e helpful.

Comment: Found that one - that is how I got to delete. Can't work out how to insert still though...

Comment: We can not tell, as we do not now your implementation of the delegate methods. I am sure inserting works in this tutorial though, so you might take a second look.

Comment: I've a link here https://github.com/stevencurtis/financecalc/blob/master/FinanceCalcSwift/StoredTableViewController.swift

Comment: Actual delegate methods are as the Apple documentation regarding them

Comment: You actually do not implement any `FetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods at all, but use the default ones from `FetchedResultsTableViewController`. Everything is explained in the tutorial.